# PHP PDO bindParam/bindValue Multiple times

Tags: php, pdo

I'm having an issue with the PDO statements for ODBC.

I'm using SQL SERVER 7 in Windows Server 2003 and PHP 5.4.x

For eg:

I have the query:

(this is not the actual query but it serves right for the example)

```
$query = SELECT * FROM table WHERE number = :number OR number = :number
```

in my php i have:

```
$conn = new PDO($connectionString);

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$statement = $conn->prepare($query);

$statement->bindParam(':number', $someNumber);

$statement->execute();
```

This throws error

```
COUNT field incorrect or syntax error
```

The thing is, bindParam is only binding the FIRST occurrence of :number ... AND trying to bind it again doesn't work either.

Is there a way to bind multiple named params with the same name?

I'm trying not to use positional params using the ? instead

Comment: The only thing that I can think of to remedy this would be to do your query `$query = SELECT * FROM table WHERE number = :number1 OR number = :number2` then do `$statement->bindParam(':number1', $someNumber1); $statement->bindParam(':number2, $someNumber2);` - There are probably other ways, but that's what I came up with. Interesting problem though.

Comment: I have thought of that, I'm trying to avoid it, I'm making a method to search the query and replace them with ? and binding by position, although I did not want to, I think is the only solution :P

Comment: If I come up with anything else, I'll let you know. Maybe someone else will have a different idea for you.

Comment: What is the problem with question mark parameters, if it serves your purpose quite well?

Comment: I just tried with question marks and it throws a different error SQLExecute[306] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254     which is related to a bug in the odbc implementation from MS

Answer (score 5):

Theoretical you could turn on emulation of prepared statements.

> You must include a unique parameter marker for each value you wish to
>   pass in to the statement when you call PDOStatement::execute(). You
>   cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in
>   a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: still, not working ... the odbc driver implementation is really messy, according to the bug reports I have found

Answer (score 1):

I don't know too much about MsSQL to be honest, but I am quite sure there is some equivalent to `User Defined Variables` in MySQL. You could use those instead of parameters like I described in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31068865/3391783

Comment: Nice. In the spirit of trying to keep information organized, if you could vote to close this question as duplicate of the other one (where your more developped answer lives), that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Just turn emulation on, changing this setting from false to true:

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
```