# What is the problem with my script PDO searching show me only 1 row?

Tags: php, search, pdo

I have a script with this lines and its doenst work for me when connected to the second sql by inner join. Its shows me only 1 rows but i have more.

```
$searchquery = '%' . $searchquery . '%';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM characters INNER JOIN accounts ON characters.accID=accounts.id WHERE accounts.aNick LIKE :searchquery OR characters.charName LIKE :searchquery");
$stmt->bindParam(':searchquery', $searchquery);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) { 
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table card-table table-striped table-vcenter">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th><center>Karakter név</center></th>
    <th><center>Account név</center></th>
    <th><center>Utolsó bejelentkezés</center></th>
    <th><center>Regisztráció</center></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
foreach ($result as $searchedPlayerInfo) { ?>
    <tr>
    <td class="w-1"><span class="avatar" style="background-image: url(./assets/images/avatar/<?php echo $searchedPlayerInfo['charAvatar'];?>.png)"></span></td>
    <td><center><a href="index.php?site=character&id=<?php echo $searchedPlayerInfo['charID'];?>" class="text-gray-dark"><?php echo $searchedPlayerInfo['charName'];?></a></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $searchedPlayerInfo['accID'];?></center></td>
    <td class="text-muted"><center><?php echo $searchedPlayerInfo['lastLoginDate'];?></center></td>
    <td class="text-muted"><center><?php echo $searchedPlayerInfo['registerDate'];?></center></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I think you need to give more details. Have you tried without the `INNER` part?

Comment: Yes. its the same only shows me 1 row.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482586/php-pdo-bindparam-bindvalue-multiple-times

Comment: Where should i put this things what is it?

Comment: You have the same placeholder 2x  `LIKE :searchquery OR characters.charName LIKE :searchquery"` and [PDOStatement::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) says `You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP PDO bindParam/bindValue Multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482586/php-pdo-bindparam-bindvalue-multiple-times)