# PHP: PDO+mysql not working with pipe sign (|)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, pipe

I have the following code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT festiwal_zdjecia (uuid, url, rok) VALUES(?, ?, ?) "
            ."ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rok = ?;");
$stmt->execute(array($uuid,$z,$rok,$rok));
```

The $z variable is equal to 'xxx|yyy.jpg'.
After running the script, in the db I can see:
url = 'xxx'.

Comment: Can HEX(url) show here ?

Comment: You are binding parameters correctly as far as I can tell so the pipe sign should not be causing any problem. How are you verifying the input data and the inserted value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Bind param to escape the pipe PDO::PARAM_STR
Refer to the following post [Use bound parameter multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511645/use-bound-parameter-multiple-times)

Comment: Having several `?` placeholders does not really count as using bound parameters multiple times (that's a problem that affects named `:foo` placeholders) and I always thought that `PDO::PARAM_STR` is the default in most drivers. I honestly can't figure out what this answer has to do with the question, nor why it's been accepted by the OP :-?

Comment: This answer was accepted because it worked (although I agree it's weird)