# mysql PDO UPDATE colours SET colour=:colour WHERE colour=:colour not working

Tags: mysql, pdo

This is my php code

```
 $update = [
    'colour' => $colour     
  ];
  
  $sql = "UPDATE colours SET colour=:colour WHERE colour=:colour";
  $stmt= $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute($update);
```

all my queries work but when I update a table with value where the value is the same it does not update. Should be an easy one for someone familiar with this problem. All help appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs at https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php :

> You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than
> once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.

It appears you need to add the following to make that query work :

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, TRUE);
```

Info found from : [Use bound parameter multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511645/use-bound-parameter-multiple-times)

Comment: I did not downvote, but I can guess that some people downvote a legitimate answer if the question is a duplicate. I've been chastised for doing that in the past.

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't even know where to start searching for this answer..